# Disable automatic www insertion in Firefox

Tags: firefox, redirection, url

If you type the URL `http://xyz.example` (even with explicit `http://`), Firefox will redirect you to `http://www.xyz.example`, even if that site does not exist. It's a really annoying behavior.

How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable Firefox's automatic URL fixup feature, do the following:

1. Type `about:config` in address line
2. Search for **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled**
3. Change the value to **false**
4. Search for **browser.urlbar.autoFill**
5. Change the value to **false**

Source: [How to disable automatic "www." prefix in Firefox](http://www.dusek.eu/how-to-disable-www-prefix-in-firefox/)

---

**However**, Firefox may not be doing this.

In the case where you navigate to a web address (e.g. `example.com`) but are redirected to a different URL (such as `www.example.com`), the redirection can be performed by the website's owner, not the browser.

There are two ways this can be done:

1. URL 301 redirect on the web server
2. CNAME record in DNS

Both methods are under the control of the owner of the `example.com` domain and cannot be defeated by changing settings in your browser.

Comment: Note: **browser.fixup.alternate.enabled** disables "fixup" which inserts "www." when the entered domain can't be resolved and **browser.urlbar.autoFill** disables auto-completion in the address bar.